# Ag-Grid Prevent tree expand/collapse when double clicking on cell

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have some code in my grid where I'm trying to prevent a double-click event from causing a tree row to expand/collapse and I can't find documentation how to do this anywhere. The reason I want to do this is so that when I double click the cell, I want to make it editable, but due to some technical necessities, I need to run `gridApi.redrawRows()` when the collapse/expand happens which causes the edit field to lose focus, meaning I can never actually edit the cell by double clicking.

I'm using the following ag-grid module versions

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^22.1.1",
"ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^22.1.1"
```

And the relevant html in my grid looks like this

```
<ag-grid-angular
        #agGrid
        class="ag-theme-balham"
        [modules]="modules"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [rowData]="rowData"
        [treeData]="true"
        (rowGroupOpened)="onRowGroupOpened($event)"
        (cellDoubleClicked)="handleCellDoubleClicked($event)"
        [getDataPath]="getDataPath"
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
        [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
        [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        [getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId"

      >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

In my component file, the particular column that is responsible for auto grouping the rows in a tree-format looks like this

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.autoGroupColumnDef = {
      editable: this.isAllowedtoEdit,
      headerName: "Account #",
      sortable: true,
      lockPosition: true,
      resizable: true,
      field: "accountNum",
      filter: "agGroupCellRenderer",
      cellRendererParams: {
        suppressCount: true,
        innerRenderer: 'AccountNameColumnDisplayer',
      },
    };
}
```

And the function for handling the double click on a cell is this:

```
handleCellDoubleClicked(cell) {
    if(cell.column.colDef.field === 'accountNum') {
      cell.event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

My `handleCellDoubleClicked()` function doesn't seem to do anything. It runs but the row still expands/collapses when I double click.

I even tried this just to see what it would do and it was causing some really weird behaviors to happen

```
handleCellDoubleClicked(cell) {
    if(cell.column.colDef.field === 'accountNum') {
      cell.node.setExpanded(false)
    }
  }
```

And finally, when I try to focus on

```
handleCellDoubleClicked(cell) {
    if(cell.column.colDef.field === 'accountNum') {
      setTimeout(() => {
         this.gridApi.startEditingCell({
           rowIndex: node.rowIndex,
           colKey: 'accountNum'
         });
      }, 125);
    }
  }
```

I get a warning in the console telling me that ag-grid does not recognize the column `accountNum`

So I'm at a bit of a loss right now. Is there something I can do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide a plinker or stackblitz sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to add the following property to your `cellRendererParams` to achieve this:

```js
cellRendererParams: {
  ...yourOtherParams,
  suppressDoubleClickExpand: true
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: what of disabling when the arrow is clicked

Comment: What do you mean exactly @KevO?

Comment: so, when you group rows in an ag grid, there is usually an arrow you're able to click which collapses or expands the row. is there a way to disable the collapse or expand function when the arrow is clicked??

Comment: @KevO I would use CSS to completely remove / hide the expand / collapse controls if they are of no use. If for some reason you still want them as a visual indicator, you could apply: "pointer-events: none;"

Comment: Note: many here may also want to include the property: suppressEnterExpand to avoid expansion if the user hits enter